# In a django save() method, how should you identify a new object if id is UUIDField?

Tags: python, django, django-models, uuid

`self.pk is None` is not working, because it is generated automatically.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override [from_db](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#customizing-model-loading)

```
@classmethod
def from_db(cls, db, field_names, values):
    instance = cls(*values)
    instance.saved = True
    return instance
```

Then in your save method the instance.saved will be available when the item is something that has already been saved in the database.

```
 def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
     if hasttr(self,'saved'):
         print 'saved'

     super(MyModel,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
     self.saved = True
```

Comment: I'd personnally use an implementation attribute and give it a more specific name to avoid potential name clash, ie : `instance._db_saved` or soemthing alike.

Comment: good point @brunodesthuilliers i leave it to the OP to sort out the cosmetics :)